# Why doesn't Firebase display events issued by my app?

Tags: android, firebase, android-productflavors

I built an app and registered it with Firebase as part of a project that includes three other apps. Here's what my buildTypes in the app gradle build file looks like:

```
        release {

        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField "int", "RULE_DEBUG_LEVEL", "0"
    }

    releaseDebuggable {

        debuggable true
        buildConfigField "int", "RULE_DEBUG_LEVEL", "1"
    }

    debug {

        //applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        versionNameSuffix " Debug"

        buildConfigField "int", "RULE_DEBUG_LEVEL", "1"


    }
```

and the productFlavors are as follows:

```
    flavorDimensions "fmplus"
productFlavors {

    String name = "fmplus"
    fmplus {
        name = "fmplus"
        applicationId getPackageName(name)
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', getAppName(name)
        resValue 'color', 'accent', getThemeColor(name)
        resValue 'color', 'accentDark', getThemeColorDark(name)
    }
    fmplus_nab_htc_one_m8 {
        name = "fmplus"
        applicationId getPackageName(name)
        applicationIdSuffix ".nab_htc_one_m8"
        versionNameSuffix "-nab_htc_one_m8"
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', getAppName(name)
        resValue 'color', 'accent', getThemeColor(name)
        resValue 'color', 'accentDark', getThemeColorDark(name)
    }
    fmplus_nyx_supraim_sn10 {
        name = "fmplus"
        applicationId getPackageName(name)
        applicationIdSuffix ".nyx_supraim_sn10"
        versionNameSuffix "-nyx-supraim-sn10"
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', getAppName(name)
        resValue 'color', 'accent', getThemeColor(name)
        resValue 'color', 'accentDark', getThemeColorDark(name)
    }
    changeFileManifest(name)
}
```

Another programmer on our team handled the flavor labelled 'fmplus_nyx_supraim_sn10' and I'm doing 'fmplus_nab_htc_one_m8'. Both apps appear in Firebase under the same project, but Firebase reports his events but not mine. I've been struggling with this for some time now and have run out of ideas. Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong. And yes, I downloaded and installed the google-services.json file and rebuilt the app before running it, just like the docs say.

Comment: could you show us your folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the app gradle file: Android Studio 3.0 requires a default dimensions statement, which I have, but what I also needed to do was add a dimension statement to the build flavor in question. The other developer, whose app didn't have this problem, was using Studio 2.3.3.